# Is there a way to stop [FromQuery] parameter to unescape the query string?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a WebAPI project using .NET Core 3.1 and I have a controller with the following action:

```
public class MyApiController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet("api/custom")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Custom([FromQuery(Name = "data")] string data)
        {
        }

}
```

I noticed that the data portion of my URL is unescaped automatically, so if I hit my service with

service.com/api/custom?data=X%3D%3D%2BY then the data field in the action method is going to hold X== Y for some reason. I think this is wrong because the %2B should be +.

In an empty project, the code snippet above correctly turned into X==+Y. In my large project, the data parameter is X== Y.

I would like to know if there is a good way to control this unescaping behavior somehow?

[UPDATE] As noted in the comment, if you do this from a mew project then the controller will give you the correct decoded string X==+Y. Updating my question to ask about how to troubleshoot issues like this?

Comment: I tested your code, and got the expected `X==+Y` (With method body = `return Ok(data);`)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I created a separate controller and it behaves as you described. But in this particular controller, does convert %2B to SPACE instead of +. I am not sure how is it different. I will investigate and will update my question

Answer (score 0):

you don' t need any extra attributes, it is only confusing.   This should be enough

```
[HttpGet("~/api/custom")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Custom(string data)
```

Comment: Great tip! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow control how the parameter from the request URL gets to the data parameter of the function?

Comment: @gyurisc Sorry, I don' t understand the question. Can you pls post the example what you want?

Comment: I tried to write another question. here is the link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621548/is-there-a-way-to-skip-the-url-query-parameter-urldecoding-in-asp-net-core-for-a/70624553#70624553