# Is there a way to skip the url query parameter urlDecoding in ASP.NET Core for a specific controller/action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following controller method:

```
public class MyApiController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet("api/custom")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Custom(string data)
        {
        }
}
```

If I hit this action method with the following query param localhost:5000/api/custom?data=Y%3D%3DX then I get the value **Y==X** for my data parameter in the Custom method.

Is it possible to disable this decoding for this method only, so I can get the original unescaped value?

Comment: For debugging? or do you need that value? cause you can always just re-encode it right?

Comment: If value should come  in this form you better should double encode it on sender side.

Comment: I just need to somehow to get in its original form. I will not be able to double encode it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.Net Core if you need to encode the characters from a query parameter, you could use [Uri.EscapeDataString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=net-6.0) in this way:

```
string dataEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(data);
```

In your **HttpGet** request it would become:

```
public class MyApiController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet("api/custom")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Custom(string data)
        {
            string dataEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(data); 
        }
}
```

You will still get the decoded string in the `data` parameter. To my knowledge, there isn't a way to completly disable **URL Decoding** on a specific controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suspect that you are right and it is not possible to disable this behavior in the framework